# Dual operating system setup

Tags: 7, iis, database

I need advice regarding my plans for a Linux/Windows web development project.

My employers have 2 windows servers - one hosts their non-drupal CMS and the other hosts the website database.
My job is to transition their website to Drupal - that's the easy part. So, I will be shutting down the server hosting the current website.

The hard part is using two separate servers for the site and the database - something I've never done before.

I plan on using a Linux server for the Drupal development but I need to know how to do the following:

- use a remote database
- use SQL Server on a Windows IIS machine

Answer (score 3):

**Remote database**

To use a remote database, you just have to supply the IP/URL of your remote server instead of 'localhost' during install or in sites/default/settings.php file.

**SQL Server**

There's a module for SQL Server : [Drupal 7 driver for SQL Server and SQL Azure](http://drupal.org/project/sqlsrv).

And [installation instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1207972) are available on the module page.